# can't configure Nvidia on my Sony Vaio VPCEH2C1E/W

Tags: nvidia, brightness, vaio, sony

i have recently bought a Sony Vaio VPCEH2C1E/W laptop on which i installed Ubuntu 11.10 64bit OS type
the graphic card is 512 MB NV GeForce 410M for which I chose (version current) [Recommended]
if I check System Info, it says Unknown
the colours are ok, but can't adjust brightness in the Screen settings (basically nothing happens)
in the Display settings menu I also get "Unknown"

i would appreciate if someone could assist me in solving this issue

thank you

Answer (score 1):

NVidia uses its own configuration software rather than integrate with Ubuntu ones; it was installed along with your drivers. You will be able to configure your monitors, among other things, with the `NVIDIA X Server Settings` application.

Comment: lots of thanx Jacob, you were right,